# Fail updating Android SDK Platform in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to update some things from the SDK Manager in eclipse. Exactly:

- Android 4.4.2: SDK Platform from Rev. 2 to 3, Google APIs form Rev. 2 to 3

When doing this, a Log appears that shows the following:

```
Failed to rename directory 
C:\Media\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platforms\android-19 to 
C:\Media\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\temp\PlatformPackage.old01.
[find_lock] Directory locked by javaw.exe
```

And then, a window appears with this message:

```
-=Warning!=-
The following processes:
- javaw.exe
are locking the following directory:
C:\Media\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platforms\android-19
Please close these aplications so that the installation can continue.
```

I can't do nothing to get it installed. I try to close this process but neither this way I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same issue a little while ago. Try restarting your computer, opening the task manager, close all the java apps/service through the task manager, start the SDK Manager with Admin, then try again.

If that doesn't work, you might want to try to close the processes after you launched the SDK Manager. If you still face the problem, you can always uninstall everything and reinstall.

Comment: Yep, I still had android studio running when SDK manager was trying to download/install the latest. I left it last night to just "figure it out" while I was gone and it made no progress and gave no indication of failure. I killed it, restarted SDK manager and tried again this morning. This time it popped up an error message that stated it couldn't rename a directory--imply that it was locked for some reason. It even popped up another message stating that something was locking that directory. Saying "yes" (to "try again?") once I closed android studio made it work.

Answer (score -1):

Closing Android Studio or eclipse(whatever is running) worked for me.

Though **SDK Manager** could  not recognize at once about the unlocking of the folder, so it poped the same warning 3-4 times after closing Android Studio. So click '**Yes**' several times(if warning appears) after closing the Android Studio/eclipse.